# How to spread bottom border of a DIV so that it overflows the bottom border of its parent?

Tags: html, css

I have a bunch of DIVs on one row, like menu items. All the items are enclosed in a container DIV. When One of the inside DIVs gets clicked, it gets the class *active*. The parent DIV has a bottom border of grey 2px, while the active child DIV gets a bottom border of green 6px.

It works as supposed to but now, I'd like the child to have shadow the parent's bottom border, so that the green part's 2 bottom pixels hide the grey ones and only 4 pixels sow above the line.

I can't simply get the grey style to all the other children because the parent has more complex looks and stretches far beyond the children.

```css
div.parent {
  border-bottom: 5px solid grey;
  display: flex;
}

div.active {
  border-bottom: 10px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">whee</div>
  <div class="child active">whoo</div>
  <div class="child">whaa</div>
</div>
```

How can I make the bottom border of the child overshadow the parent's bottom border by rendering it 2 pixels lower (or by any other means)?

Comment: Can you also include a [mcve] of what you have so far?

Comment: You mentioned DIVs multiple times but it seems that you really meant button

Comment: @j08691 Same effect on both. I can update the example. I tried both just to make sure it behaved consequently prior to asking. Or rather **misbehaved**. The same point in question remains - how do I CSS'ize the inner element's bottom border imposing it over the outer element's bottom border.

Comment: @j08691 Thanks for the edit. I wasn't aware that one could go fiddling like this in edit mode directly in SO. Nice!

Comment: @blurfus I can and I have.

Comment: I see it now ;)

Comment: @blurfus Oh, it was there already. You just looked from the wrong point of time...   :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might set a negative `margin-bottom` on `.child`:

```css
div.parent {
  border-bottom: 5px solid grey;
  display: flex;
}

.child {margin-bottom:-5px}

div.active {
  border-bottom: 10px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">whee</div>
  <div class="child active">whoo</div>
  <div class="child">whaa</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is the look you want to achieve but I added this to the `.active` class.

```
div.active {
  border-bottom: 10px solid green;
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
}
```

**See demo**

```css
div.parent {
  border-bottom: 10px solid grey;
  display: flex;
}

div.active {
  border-bottom: 10px solid green;
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">whee</div>
  <div class="child active">whoo</div>
  <div class="child">whaa</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

a possible solution could be this:

```css
div.parent {
  border-bottom: 5px solid grey;
  display: flex;
}

div.active {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0 10px;
}

div.active:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 10px solid green;
  bottom: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">whee</div>
  <div class="child active">whoo</div>
  <div class="child">whaa</div>
</div>
```